# Finding differentiability of a function. Help?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

$ f(x) = |x| + |x+1| + |x-2|$

I need to find if this is differentiable at x=1.
How do I solve a question like above to find differentiability?

Now I have come across two different formulas to find left hand derivative.

$\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x-h) - f(x)}{-h}$

$\lim\limits_{h \to 0-} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$

Which one of the above is correct one? 
If both are correct, how is that possible?

Comment: HINT: When $x$ is very close to $1$, $$f(x)=x+(x+1)+(2-x)=x+3\;.$$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I am sorry I am struggling with this and the hint isn't enough

Comment: $\dfrac{ (x-h+3)-(x+3)}{-h}=\dfrac{(x+h+3)-(x+3)}h=1$

Comment: First, you don’t need the left-hand derivative: you just want to prove that the derivative exists. The derivative of $f$ at $x=1$ is defined as $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}h\;.$$ Since that limit depends only on what happens when $h$ is close to $0$, you need concern yourself with $f(1+h)$ only when $1+h$ is close to $1$, and that allows you to get rid of the absolute values. Then it becomes a very straightforward limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the absolute value is defined by cases,
$$|x|=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
x & \text{if }x\geq 0;\\
-x & \text{if }x\lt 0,
\end{array}\right.$$
$$|x+1|=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
x+1 & \text{if }x\geq -1;\\
-x-1 & \text{if }x\lt -1,
\end{array}\right.$$
$$|x-2|=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
x-2 & \text{if }x\geq 2;\\
2-x & \text{if }x\lt 2,
\end{array}\right.$$

near $x=1$ we have

$$f(x)=x+(x+1)+(2-x)=x+3.$$

To find if $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x=1$, use the definition of the derivative:

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h},$$
$$\text{at x=1:}\quad\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h},$$
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(4+h)-4}{h}=1.$$

Therefore, $f(x)$ is differentiable as $x=1$ since we have shown that $f'(1)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

We don't need to find left hand derivatives in this question. We just need to analyse the given function for $x=1+h$ with $h$ small. So
$$f\left(1+h\right)=\left\lvert1+h\right\rvert+\left\lvert2+h\right\rvert+\left\lvert-1+h\right\rvert$$
Since $h$ is small, $1+h,2+h$ will be positive and $-1+h$ will be negative. So, using the definition of absolute value,
we have

$$f\left(1+h\right)=1+h+2+h-\left(-1+h\right)=4+h=f\left(1\right)+h$$
So we see that $$\frac{f\left(1+h\right)-f\left(1\right)}h=1$$ for all small $h$. So when we take the limit $h\to0$, the limit exists, and so $f$ is differentiable at $x=1$. Now, the definition of left hand derivative is
$$\lim\limits_{h\to0^+}\frac{f\left(x-h\right)-f\left(x\right)}h$$ where $h\to0^+$ means take the limit $h\to0$ from the positive direaction. However, taking $h\to0$ from positive direction is same as taking $-h\to0$ along negative. So we can rewrite as

$$\lim\limits_{-h\to0^-}\frac{f\left(x+\left(-h\right)\right)-f\left(x\right)}h$$
Now, renaming $-h$ as $h$, we obtain the second definition
$$\lim\limits_{h\to0^-}\frac{f\left(x+h\right)-f\left(x\right)}h$$
Sence your two definitions of left hand derivative are equal. however, we do not need that to answer this question.